# Python asyncio timely event handling

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-3.5, event-driven

I'm playing a bit with python's asyncio library, in the wake of [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-using-transport-and-protocol), I wrote the following scripts:

```
# file: get_rand.py
from random import choice
from time import sleep
import sys

def main():
    sys.stderr.write('child: starting loop...\n')
    for _ in range(5):
        print(choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
        sys.stderr.write('child: going to sleep\n')
        sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and:

```
# file: async_test.py
import asyncio
import time


class Protocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):

    def __init__(self, exit_f):
        self.exit = exit_f
        print('Protocol initialised')

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        print('Data received')
        if fd == 1:
            with open('rand_file.txt', 'a') as out:
                out.write(bytes(data).decode('ascii'))
        elif fd == 2:
            print('Received error data!')
            print(data)

    def pipe_connection_lost(self, fd, exc):
        print('Pipe connection lost')
        if exc is not None:
            print(exc)
            raise exc

    def process_exited(self):
        self.exit.set_result(True)
        print('Subprocess exited')


@asyncio.coroutine
def mycoro():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    exit_future = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)
    print('creating process...')
    subprocess = loop.subprocess_exec(lambda: Protocol(exit_future),
                                      'python3.5', 'get_rand.py',
                                      stdin=None, stderr=None)
    transp, proto = yield from subprocess
    print('waiting for subprocess to finish...')
    yield from exit_future
    transp.close()


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(mycoro())
    loop.close()
```

When executing this code, I get the following:

```
$ python3.5 async_test.py 
creating process...
Protocol initialised
waiting for subprocess to finish...
child: starting loop...
child: going to sleep 
child: going to sleep 
child: going to sleep 
child: going to sleep 
child: going to sleep 
Data received
Pipe connection lost
Subprocess exited
```

I have many questions about all this:

1. Apparently the data the child sends trigger the pipe_data_received event only once and after the child has terminated. Is there a way to spawn a child process and have the pipe_data_received event triggered at every write on stdout?
2. If I remove the line `transp, proto = yield from subprocess` the whole thing just hangs on `creating process...`, so it looks like the child is not started until the parent does `transp, proto = yield from subprocess`. Is that correct? Why is that?
3. What if I wanted my process to spawn a child which runs forever and periodically triggers the pipe_data_received, while the lauching process keeps its execution flow, and does other stuff? Is this the right tool for such a need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.

`print` writes data to stdout buffers, by default they are flushed only once.  You can add explicit `flush`.

```
for _ in range(5):
   print(choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

or on ptyhon3.3 and above

```
for _ in range(5):
    print(choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), flush=True)
```

More info [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print).

#### 2.

The `subprocess_exec` returns coroutine. Every coroutine that you want to run  must be scheduled on the loop. `yield from` just schedules it and wait until it's done (for `subprocess_exec` done means process is executed).

#### 3.

To run task in background, you have to as well schedule it on loop, but do not wait for results. You can use [ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future).

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def mycoro():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    exit_future = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)
    print('creating process...')
    subprocess = loop.subprocess_exec(lambda: Protocol(exit_future),
                                      'python3.5', 'get_rand.py',
                                      stdin=None, stderr=None)
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(subprocess)
    print('Subprocess is handled in the background task')

    # this function is called with run_until_complete, 
    # since that returning means complete we would not
    # finish subprocess task
    # so im leaving it
    yield from exit_future
```

**edit**

And here simple example of running loop forever. I have removed all `exit_future` related stuff, as it is not needed.

```
import asyncio
import time


class Protocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Protocol initialised')

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        print('Data received %s' % data)
        if fd == 1:

            with open('rand_file.txt', 'a') as out:
                out.write(bytes(data).decode('ascii'))
        elif fd == 2:
            print('Received error data!')
            print(data)


    def pipe_connection_lost(self, fd, exc):
        print('Pipe connection lost')
        if exc is not None:
            print(exc)
            raise exc

    def process_exited(self):
        print('Subprocess exited')


@asyncio.coroutine
def mycoro():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    print('creating process...')
    subprocess = loop.subprocess_exec(lambda: Protocol(),
                                      'python3.5', 'get_rand.py',
                                      stdin=None, stderr=None)
    asyncio.ensure_future(subprocess)
    asyncio.ensure_future(dummy_work())
    print('Mycoro finished, tasks are scheduled')


@asyncio.coroutine
def dummy_work():
    while True:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('dummy work')

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(mycoro())
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()

main()


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(mycoro())
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()

main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer. Just one more question: in this case `yield from exit_future` blocks until the subprocess terminates? In case I wanted to keep execution outside of `mycoro()` while the subprocess was running (i.e. the protocol handles the data I receive from the subprocess while I do something else), how would I do that?